# How can replacing NSString use array to another array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

Hi
How can i replace NSString use array to another array
like this

```
@"Hello world"
```

{a,b,c,d,e,...} -> {1,2,3,4,5,..} = @"H5llo worl4"

and can i replace without array??
totally i want to replace 10 characters of an String to another 10 characters.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array and replace each character in turn :

```
// Get the two arrays of characters to replace and their replacements
NSArray *fromArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", nil];
NSArray *toArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];

// Make a mutable version of our string
NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello World"];

// Deal with each replacement in turn
for (uint n = 0; n < [fromArray count]; ++n)
    [newString replaceOccurrencesOfString:[fromArray objectAtIndex:n] withString:[toArray objectAtIndex:n] options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];

// Output the new string
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

This code's not great though - what if the two arrays are different lengths?

Comment: Thanks no they have same length.

Comment: @mamrezo you'd better have a look at efficiency here and maybe correctness if you can have overlapping substitutions

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to store your associative array (which contains the replacement string and its key).

Then you can loop through your elements in the NSDictionary using a **[fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html)** so that you can could substitute it by using [`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`](http://stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3aoptions%3arange%3a).

This method is better than simply calling `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:` because by specifying the range you can avoid from re-looping on an already subsituted substring and also you will avoid the application of chained substitutions (ie. `a->i, i->4`)